# Javascript facebook api , methods available on a LIKE button of facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My aim is to create a javaScript which will CLICK on All the LIKE buttons on all the posts loaded in the facebook webpage, chrome browser.

Input:   "https://www.facebook.com/akshay4497mane"   Or any other FB page,Groups,Profiles

Step1: I will scroll down to load all the posts

Step 2: Obtain LIKE buttons in an array and call CLICK()

```
LikeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('_48-k UFILikeLink');

for(var i = 0 ; i < LikeButtons.length ; i++){
       LikeButtons[i].click(); 
}
```

But the problem here is that CLICK() method by default is designed to TOGGLE the LIKE STATUS, ie. If the Button is LIKED it will UNLIKE it, If button is UNLIKED it will LIKE it.

However , So i want to check the status(like/unlike) of the button before calling click() method.

IS there anyway i can figure out what all other methods are available on LIKE button?
*I tried isClick(). isLiked() methods as random guess, not working

Comment: may i ask what the use case for this is? sounds like you are trying to do something that is definitely not allowed.

Comment: To like all the posts of your GF as and when she uploads.

Comment: my GF is not on facebook ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
LikeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('_48-k UFILikeLink');

for(var i = 0 ; i < LikeButtons.length ; i++){
    if(LikeButtons[i].hasAttribute("data-testid") && LikeButtons[i]. getAttribute("data-testid") == "fb-ufi-likelink") {
        LikeButtons[i].click(); 
    }
}
```